# exceeding the size limit of matrix in R

Tags: r, memory, size, large-data, r-bigmemory

I'm using fDMA model in R language. The input of this model is x, y. In my case,x contains 194 features. The problem is that the model constructs a matrix containing all the combinations of models that we can build with these 194 features(here, the total number of combinations is 2^194), and them make the estimations.
As there is a limit in R for the size of a matrix(2^51), I get error after running the model. Is there any way to handle this problem without reducing the size of the combination matrix?

I tried with bigmemory. However as the combination matrix is constructing in the model, I was able to make the input variable(x) as a big matrix and it didn't work.(I'm not sure if I've done it correctly)

Comment: The matrix would have to contain a double precision floating point number for each of 2^194 combinations. That's 2 * 10^57 entries, which is about 10 times as many atoms as there are in the sun. To store all these combinations would require approximately 10,000 quadrillion quadrillion times the entire digital storage of every electronic device on the planet, and calculating them on the fastest supercomputer would take several thousand times the current age of the universe. In other words, you need to reduce the size of the combination matrix.

Comment: @AllanCameron Whilst it does succinctly demonstrate the issue at hand, I imagine that response was also rather fun to write :D